# wxpython: detect whether a dialog has been closed

Tags: python, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog, wxpython

I am using wxpython to create a GUI and I have the following customized dialog class:

```
class GetDataDlg(wx.Dialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parameters = kwargs.pop('parameters', None)
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        assert self.parameters is not None
        assert request is not None
        strings = re.findall('[A-Z][a-z]*', request)
        info = ""
        for string in strings:
            if len(string) == 1:
                info = info + string
            elif not info:
                info = string.lower()
            else:
                info = info + " " + string.lower()

        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.data = {}

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        input_text = wx.StaticText(self, label="Please type the new {}".format(info))
        main_sizer.Add(input_text, 1, wx.ALL, 10)
        input_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        main_sizer.Add(input_sizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        text_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        input_sizer.Add(text_sizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.RIGHT, 10)
        ctrl_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        input_sizer.Add(ctrl_sizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.controls = controls = {}

        for key in self.parameters:
            text = wx.StaticText(self, label=key)
            text_sizer.Add(text, 0, wx.BOTTOM, 17)
            ctrl = controls[key] = wx.TextCtrl(self)
            ctrl_sizer.Add(ctrl, 0, wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        ok_button = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_OK)
        main_sizer.Add(ok_button, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT | wx.BOTTOM, 10)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)
        self.Fit()
        self.Layout()

        ok_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.save_data)

    def save_data(self, event):
        for item in self.parameters:
            self.data[item] = self.controls[item].GetValue()
        event.Skip()
```

In my main frame I call the dialog like this:

```
dlg = GetDataDlg(self, parameters=parameter, request=item)
result = dlg.ShowModal()
```

Now I need to detect whether the user has pushed the ok button provided by my code or the close button in the right upper part of the dialog provided by the class itself. `result` does not seem to change in the two cases, neither do other attributes of `dlg`. Besides I cannot check the existence of `dlg.data`, because the dialog appears to save the values even when pushing the close button.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That's weird. When the dialog is closed using the button, ShowModal should return its id (wx.ID_OK in your case). When I close the dialog, I get wx.ID_CANCEL. What is the actual value you got from ShowModal?

Comment: @PetrBlahos thanks for your answer. I get result = {int} 5100 in the debugger. Am I visualizing wrongly the id?

Comment: ID_OK is 5100, ID_CANCEL is 5101. It is weird, that when you close the dialog, you get ID_OK. What platform, and wx version are you on?

Comment: I am on Windows and I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.4. The wxPython version is 3.0.3.dev2487+3b86464 and version of Python intepreter is 3.4.4.

Comment: Try changing OK button's id to ID_CANCEL and see if there is a difference between pressing the button and closing the dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried the ID_CANCEL and I get result = {int} 5101 for both cases (my button and dialog's close button). So the dialog's close button seems to be associated with my button. Is it possible to override it by any chance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123538/discussion-between-petr-blahos-and-francesco).

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding the close event.
Have you tried inserting a `self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnQuit)` where OnQuit returns wx.ID_CANCEL